# SET in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Is it possible to use `SET` in a prepared statement?

The following doesn't work but shows what I want to achieve:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SET @var = ?;
                          SELECT id... (big query that uses @var many times)");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $var);
```

I have also tried to use `multi_query` without any luck.

The alternative is to write the following which looks bad:

```
$stmt->bind_param('iiiiiiii', $var, $var, $var, $var, $var, $var, $var, $var);
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is just to initialize it in the query itself.  Somewhere, deep down in the query, do:

```
select . . .
from . . . cross join
     (select @var = ?) vars
```